# Any recommendations for buying SINAD measuring equipment?

Tags: signal-analysis, noise, software-defined-radio, distortion

I am interested in buying a device that measures the SINAD of the audio signal(FM signal) that I receive from PC. Here is the setup :
Signal generator -> attenuator ->HackRF connected to PC with SDR#

When we receive a 1KHZ FM signal generated by the signal generator at the HackRF(which is connected to PC), we get an audio tone from the PC as output. I am interested in measuring the audio quality of FM tone that we receive at hackrf (connected to PC with SDR# support).

I know that for some signal generators, there is a separate port for measuring SINAD. The signal generator that I have does not have the capability to measure the SINAD. So, if there are any other devices that can help me measure this SINAD, please let me know.

Comment: I'm confused: you mention a PC, but it appears nowhere in your setup description? What kind of audio (analog, digital) are we talking about?

Comment: This question should be closed, there is a new version of it [here](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/q/58546/4298).