# Recommendations for SINAD equipment

Tags: signal-analysis, noise, software-defined-radio, distortion

I am interested in buying a device that measures the SINAD of the audio signal(FM signal) that I receive from PC. 
Here is the setup:

Signal generator (generating 1kHz FM signal ) $\rightarrow$ attenuator $\rightarrow$ HackRF connected to PC with SDR#

When we receive a 1kHz FM signal generated by the signal generator at the HackRF (which is connected to PC), we get an audio tone from the PC as output. I am interested in measuring the audio quality of FM tone that we receive at hackrf (connected to PC with SDR# support).

I know that for some signal generators, there is a separate port for measuring SINAD. The signal generator that I have does not have the capability to measure the SINAD. So, if there are any other devices that can help me measure this SINAD, please let me know.

Note: Sorry, I asked the same question without registering in dsp.stackexchanege ([Any recommendations for buying SINAD measuring equipment?](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/58544/any-recommendations-for-buying-sinad-measuring-equipment)). I was unable to edit the question. So created a new one here.

Answer (score 1):

So, you've got the audio signal in digital on your PC.

**Analyze that digitally**; you don't need any measurement equipment to do that.

On the contrary: Measuring properties of the analog audio signal is highly undesirable, because you'd be including the sound card of your laptop in your measurement, but you probably don't care about that even remotely. If you actually wanted to know the properties of your sound card, *then* you'd need to separately measure that – but you'd do that with a "clean" test signal generated by your PC, not something received over a noise system.

Comment: You mentioned that there is no need for a device to measure SINAD. It is possible to find the SNR of a signal at a particular frequency in SDR#. But how do I measure the distortion? If possible, can you elaborate a bit more on how I need to conduct the SINAD measurement?

Comment: I don't know SDR#, but I know that it somehow gives you a digital audio sample stream that you give to your sound card. Capture that, do the standard SINAD calculation on that.